# Scaffolding EntityFramework 6 Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, scaffolding

I wanna use Scaffolding in EntityFrameWork 6, but get this:

> Unable to retrieve metadata for '[myNameSpace].Models.prod'. Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'.

Does EF 6 support scaffolding?

**Update**

After some while, [microsoft realease new upgrade for support scafolding and some others features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

I think it doesn't work while you upgrade vs IDE to 2013

Comment: Hi Edalat, do you make works the EF 6 with Scaffolding?
I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 with EF 6 and I tryed update to ASP.NET MVC 5 without sucess. I used this tutorial to upgrade to MVC 5 http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2 but the error persists.
What did you do for work? What do you have installed?

Comment: Hi @ViniciusdeLemos I installed vs 2013 and it works

Comment: I think it doesn't work while you upgrade vs IDE to 2013

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm sorry but it is not supported
[ASP.NET MVC 4 scaffolding does not support Entity Framework 6 or later](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2816241)

Answer (score 5):

I was battling with this kind of problem for almost 3 days, but I later found two solutions:

**Command**

1. Open an empty MVC Solution
2. Open your Package manager console
3. Type this command (Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0 )

**Default Framework**

Select an internet application option of the ASP.NET MVC project template on Visual Studio 2012. By default Entity framework 5 came with it so there is no need to run your package manager console again.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC 4 scaffolding does not support Entity Framework 6 or later version.

1.Need to uninstall Entity framework6 or later version
Tools->NuGet package manager->Package manager console
PM> uninstall-package entityframework -version 6.1.1

2.Install entity framework 5

PM> install-package entityframework -version 5.0.0.0

3.Need to change web.config

To change as it bellow

Comment: But i ask how scaffolding in EF 6